# jquery slide flashing/blink issue on Firefox ubuntu

Tags: jquery, firefox, ubuntu, slide

I have a `<ul>` list that is a little bit long. When you expand (slide down) that list elements, the browser does NOT scroll down and everything’s alright. When you contract (slide up) that list of elements, the browser scrolls up will flash/blink A **lot** while doing so.

- This doesn't happen on MAC Firefox.
- Neither on Windows (at least the versions I could test)
- This occurs severely on Firefox Linux (ubuntu).

Does anyone had this issue before? If so, what can we do to solve it?

Here's a code sample for better understanding:

```
$('#btCatA').click(function() {
    $('#btCatA').toggleClass('selec');
    $('#listcatA').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably prevent this by decreasing the `scrollTop` property of the `window` object by the height of that element **before** you slide up your list elements. jQuery has a method for that: [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop). You could animate that, too so that it looks a bit less hasty. The following (untested) code should do the trick:

```
var toggleClass = 'selec';

$('#btCatA').click(function() {
    var target = $(this),
        listElement = $('#listcatA');

    if (target.hasClass(toggleClass)) {
        target.removeClass(toggleClass);
        $(window).animate({
            scrollTop: '-='+listElement.height()+'px'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            listElement.slideUp('slow');
        });
    } else {
        target.addClass(toggleClass);
        listElement.slideDown('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry for this, I've just updated my question- Can you please have a look, and, if it still applies, point where that .scroolTop should be placed? thks a lot.ps- the element is dynamicly (php) builded, so, there's no fixed height.

Comment: @MEM: You need to do that `scrollTop`-thing before you slide. Put the slide-action in the callback of your `scrollTop`-animation (slide up only, slide down should be handled separately).

Comment: @elusise: let me be honest. I can't. I'm not sure where to code that. You said the place, callback of my scroolTop, ok... but what should I write on scroolTop? I'm lost. sorry, quite newbie here. :s